# ODBC not connected HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, odbc

The title may be misleading. I apologize for that.
Anyways, I am confused about SQL and ODBC.

On my website, I am trying to setup a register page.
Basically, on my dedicated server with MYSQL running on it, I setup some register.php files so that when a person registers on the site, it gets put into a certain database in SQL. When I try to register, I get "odbc not connected" Do I need to add a new data source?
Example of the html/php file: "Register.php"

```
    <?php
$aw=$_GET["q"];
$aws=$_GET["q2"];
$awts=$_GET["q3"];
$conn = odbc_connect('USER_MEMBERDB','Test','Test123');
//$sql="SELECT * FROM chr_log_info WHERE id_loginid = '$q'";
if ($conn) 
{ 
  $query = "select * from chr_log_info where id_loginid = '$aw'";  
  //perform the query 
  $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query)or die("Error Here!");; 

 // $aw = mssql_escape_string($aw);
 // $aws = mssql_escape_string($aws);

  $slashRead1 = "";
  $slashRead2 = ""; 
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($aw); $i++){
    if($aw[$i] == '\\'){
        $slashRead1 = 'yah';
    }
  }

  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($aws); $i++){
    if($aws[$i] == '\\'){
        $slashRead2 = 'yah';
    }
  }

  if(!empty($slashRead1) && !empty($slashRead2)){
    echo "Username and Password values cannot be accepted. Please change your Username and Password!";
  }else if(!empty($slashRead1)){
    echo "Username value cannot be accepted. Please change your Username!";
  }else if(!empty($slashRead2)){
    echo "Password value cannot be accepted. Please change your Password!";
  }else{
    if(empty($aws)){
        echo "Please fill-in the form completely!";
    }else{
        $count = 0;
        //fetch tha data from the database by row 
        while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){ 
            for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result);$i++){ 
                $row = odbc_result($result, $i);
                    if(!empty($row)){
                        $count++;
                    }
            }
        }

            if(empty($aw)){
            echo "Please fill-in the form completely!";
            }else if($count != 0){
            echo "Sorry, the username you entered is not available!";
            }else if(strlen($aws) < 6){
            echo "Please enter more than 6 characters for your password!";
        }else{
            $query1 = "Select id_idx from chr_log_info";
            $result1=odbc_exec($conn, $query1)or die("Error Here!");;
            while(odbc_fetch_row($result1)){
                for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result1);$i++){
                    $row = odbc_result($result1, $i);
                }
            }
            $row++;
            $query2 = "Select propid from chr_log_info";
            $result2=odbc_exec($conn, $query2)or die("Error Here!");;
            while(odbc_fetch_row($result2)){
                for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result2);$i++){
                    $row2 = odbc_result($result2, $i);
                }
            }
            $row2++;
            $query3 = "Insert into chr_log_info(id_idx, propid, id_loginid, id_passwd, id_sexType) values('$row', '$row2', '$aw', '$aws', '$awts')";
            $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query3) or die("Error Here!");
            echo "Congratulations! You have successfully registered!";
            }
    }
   }
   //close the connection 
   odbc_close ($conn);
} 
else echo "odbc not connected"; 
?>
```

Another HTML file that is used is this: "responsexml.html"

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$conn = odbc_connect('USER_MEMBERDB','Test','Test123');
if ($conn) 
{ 
  $q = mysql_escape_string($q);

  $slashRead = "";
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($q); $i++){
    if($q[$i] == '\\'){
        $slashRead = 'yah';
    }
  }

  if(!empty($slashRead)){
    echo "Username value cannot be accepted!";
  }else{  
    //the SQL statement that will query the database 
    $query = "select * from chr_log_info where id_loginid = '$q'";  
    //perform the query 
    $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query) or die("Wrong!"); 

    //fetch tha data from the database 
    $count = 0;
    while($row = odbc_fetch_row($result)) 
    { 
        for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result);$i++) 
        { 
          $row = odbc_result($result, $i);
            if(!empty($row)){
              $count++;
          }
        }
    }

    if(empty($q)){
        echo "";
    }else if($count != 0){
        echo "Sorry, the username is not available!";
    }else{
        echo "Username is available!";
    }
   }

  //close the connection 
  odbc_close ($conn); 
} 
else echo "odbc not connected"; 
?>
```

Am I missing something? Or do I need to download certain drivers for my dedicated server for it to run. Any suggestions?

Comment: .html? have you instructed your server to treat .html as .php?

Comment: you can use .php file use mysql_connect instead of odbc_connect

Comment: My bad, I meant to put .php, I changed it.

Comment: @priya786 I changed what you told me, still get no connection at all.

Comment: you can also select the particular db

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `USER_MEMBERDB` that is in your `odbc_connect` is the name of the MSSQL database that you are trying to connect to.

You could try:

```
// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver -  allows connection to SQL 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008
 $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
```

However, I would recommend using the built in MSSQL functions over ODBC for this purpose:

```
$conn = mssql_connect('SERVER', 'username', 'password');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows Server you can add the ODBC connection on the pc. Usually I use PDO to connect to the Database (not odbc_connect as you)
In principle, this should also work without a user and password. If defined in interface.

```
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:dsnName','user','password');`
```